# Toolbar is not shown in activities when extending Base Activity that implements ToolBar

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am a beginner Android developer and I have been struggling the issue that I can't see the toolbar in any activity that inherits Base Activity. According to other resource, to use the same toolbar in the different activities. I have to implement it in Base Activity and inherit it where I need to use it. Could anyone help me figure out the problem?

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
</resources>
```

quiz.menu.xml inside of menu folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/contact"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_24dp"
    android:title="Contact"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item android:id="@+id/language"
    android:title="Language"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/speech"
    android:title="Speech"
    app:showAsAction="never">

    <munu>
        <item android:id="@+id/subitem1"
            android:title="Sub Item 1"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/subitem2"
            android:title="Sub Item 2"/>
    </munu>
</item>
</menu>
```

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.quiz_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.contact:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.language:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Language is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.speech:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Speech is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.subitem1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Language is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.subitem2:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Speech is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

WelcomeActivity (inherits base Activity)

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    final Button databaseButton = findViewById(R.id.database);
    databaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            Intent databaseIntent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, Questionnaire.class);
            startActivity(databaseIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Questionnaire

```
public class Questionnaire extends BaseActivity {
public Spinner languageSpinner;
public int languageId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questionnaire);
    ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually simple. You firstly set contentview in `OnCreate()` method of the BaseActivity class, then you change the view to another xml file in `OnCreate()` methods of the child classes.

What I suggest is that you do not implement `OnCreate()` method in BaseActivity class but implement `SetContentView()` method in BaseActivity.

In short, delete `onCreate()` method from BaseActivity() and add `setContentView()` method in the below.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

P.S - Your `quiz_menu.xml` file does not look like a menu file. :)
P.P.S - Let me know if it works, or if you have troubles. :)

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I tried what you did, but it was not working yet. Also, thank you for pointing out quiz.menu file. I modified it.

Comment: @YudaiYaguchi do your layout files (`activity_questionnaire` and `activity_welcome`) contain toolbar?

Comment: adding some `protected` method to `BaseActivity`, which sets up the content-view as well the `Toolbar` as a `SupportActionBar`, might be the least mess... because classes which would extend the `BaseActivity`, just would have to provide the according `resId`s, of layout & toolbar... one cannot assume that the `resId` of the toolbar will always be `R.id.toolbar` (eg. in apps, which require several different toolbars).